# Creating a function that reads files and checks whether they are left justified

Tags: python, file

I need to create a function that will use a file that's open for reading and returns a boolean if every line in the file is left justified.

So far I have

```
def justified(parameters):
  value = True
  for index, line in enumerate(parameters):
     if index > 0 and (line.startswith("") or line.startswith("\t")):
        value = false
    return value
```

The issue I am having is that this works for when one line is left justified, a blank line is left justified, and multiple lines are left justified, but does not work when I have one single line of text that is not left justified, or when a file contains multiple text that is not left justified, or a file has a line with only spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check if your file is left-justified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208877/how-to-check-if-your-file-is-left-justified)

Comment: Your code indentation seems odd.

Comment: Also, I guess `false` should be `False` and any `str` *always* starts with `""` by definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
def justified(file):
  for line in file:
     if line.startswith(" ") or line.startswith("\t"):
        return True
  return False
```

I have changed a couple of things in your `function` (above) so that it should work as intended now:

- gave it a sensible parameter name
- removed unnecessary `variable` as `return` `escapes` the `function`
- took out check for `index` being `> 0` as I don't see its function
- changed the `empty` `string` for a `space` to an actual `space`